# how to set multiple notification for days from sunday to saturday

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an alarm [image: application] in which i am  setting notification for a particular day i.e  today's date that i chose from date picker and set on the firedate property of the notification.This works properly and my notification is displayed properly but i have page where when the user selects every monday the notification should be displayed for every monday and if the user selects every monday, every wednesday ,every thursday notification should be displayed for every monday,wednesday and thursday.Please help me in solving my problem.Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are having. Did you try it and get an error or are you not sure how to begin?

Comment: @sosborn ya i am able to do for single day notification i.e for selecting time from date picker and setting it to the notification.but this i am getting confused on how to start.Please can u help me

Answer (score 0):

For that You Have to schedule 3 different notification for monday , wednesday , thursday ..according to your requirement. then set repeat interval for all three notification as a weekly like

localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

Comment: if the user choses any random days then how could i set the notification for that

Comment: but i think you have some idea about for which day user select..so by detecting the day you can easily set firedate for notification...and you can also use addtimeinterval function dateByAddingTimeInterval...

Comment: plz don't ignore the limitation .....  Each application on a device is limited to the soonest-firing 64 scheduled local notifications. The operating system discards notifications that exceed this limit. It considers a recurring notification to be a single notification.